# My Fedora 22 unable to discover wifi networks?

Tags: fedora, wifi

It worked fine till yesterday all of sudden it is unable discover nearby access points.Even I tried to connect to manually it didn't work

```
lspci | grep BCM
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

lsmod | grep wl
wl                   6369280  0 
cfg80211              548864  1 wl
```

Comment: try running "rfkill list" and check that your device is not hard blocked or soft blocked

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have to install Boradcom drivers to get the correct behavior.
I had the same issue and after few tries I could install the drivers and issue is gone.

Install RPMFusions free and non free versions using these two commands. Change version number (22) according to your version. My installed fedora version is 22.

```
rpmkeys --import "http://rpmfusion.org/keys?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-22" "http://rpmfusion.org/keys?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-nonfree-fedora-22"
```

Then

```
dnf install http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-22.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-22.noarch.rpm
```

Now your *.rpms are ready. Lets continue to install the drivers. Run below command to install the necessary packages.

```
 dnf install kmod-wl akmod.wl kernel_devel
```

Here is the step by step guide.http://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2015/12/how-to-install-broadcom-drivers-in.html